# How to convert a map location (lat, lng) pair to a screen position (x, y) pair in mapbox

Tags: javascript, position, location, mapbox

I am using [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/) javascript API to do some cool stuff on a map. Now I have a map location (latitude, longitude) pair and I want to set the view to this location then use javascript to simulate a click at this location. The problem is that I need to find out the screen position (x, y) pair of this location after setting the view. But how do I do that?

It seems there is an API [L.ICRS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-icrs/). I tried but it returned NaN for both x and y -- please check my example javascript codes below.

```
var latlng = [40.444621, -79.943231]
map.setView(latlng, 13);
L.CRS.EPSG3857.latLngToPoint(latlng, 13);
```

Can anybody help me on that? My final goal is to simulate a click at that position.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

## Mapbox.js

Use the [latLngToContainerPoint](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint) method off of the `map` object.

## Mapbox GL JS

[project](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#project) is the equivalent function for GL.

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve that for Mapbox GL ?

Comment: project() is the equivalent function for GL: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#project