# Line or Polygon Object point in Mapbox-gl-js

Tags: javascript, polygon, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I work with Mapbox-GL.
I'm blocking on something that needs to be obvious.

How can I convert geometry (lng / lat) to point (x, y)?

There is a "Javascript library" <s>bookseller</s> for this?

Then, if it's a point, line, polygon or multipolygon ...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "JavaScript bookseller"?

Comment: Sorry, "Javascript library" (turf or anything...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `project` method of the map object.

[image: project description]

The screenshot is taken from the [mapbox-gl-js documentation on `project`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#project).

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085119/4481169

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I use `map#project` and this package "geojson-project"
https://github.com/w8r/geojson-project

Code sample:
```js
var shape = geojsonProject(object, function(coord) {
    var pt = map.project(coord.slice())
    return [pt.x, pt.y];
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`map#project` and "geojson-project" github.com/w8r/geojson-project

Code sample:

```
var shape = geojsonProject(object, function(coord) {
    var pt = map.project(coord.slice())
    return [pt.x, pt.y];
},
```